# How to create GeoSpatial index in MongoDB using C++

Tags: c++, mongodb, geospatial, mongo-cxx-driver

In python/pymongo, creating GeoSpatial index is quite trivial:

```
db.collection.create_index([("loc", GEO2D)], min=-100, max=100)
```

After that I can insert data using "loc" field.

But in C++/mongocxx, after referring mongocxx document (http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-cxx-driver/mongocxx-v3/tutorial/) and GeoSpatial docement, I still cannot figure out how to do this.

Could anyone kindly show me how to deal with Geospatial index in C++? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a GeoSpatial index with the C++ driver in a similar way to the Python driver; the main difference is that instead of passing the minimum and maximum as direct arguments to `create_index`, they're instead set in an `options::index` object which is then passed to `create_index`. Here's a short program that creates the index you described above using the C++ driver:

```
#include <bsoncxx/builder/basic/document.hpp>
#include <bsoncxx/builder/basic/kvp.hpp>
#include <mongocxx/client.hpp>
#include <mongocxx/instance.hpp>
#include <mongocxx/options/index.hpp>
#include <mongocxx/uri.hpp>

using namespace mongocxx;
using bsoncxx::builder::basic::kvp;

int main() {
    instance inst{};

    client conn{uri{}};
    auto coll = conn["db_name"]["coll_name"];

    bsoncxx::builder::basic::document index_doc;
    index_doc.append(kvp("loc", "2d"));

    coll.create_index(
        index_doc.extract(),
        options::index{}
            .twod_location_min(-100).twod_location_max(100));
```

}